# angular2 how to print value of object array

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to print a value => `id` of an array which looks like this:

```
locations = [
    {id: '1',  lat: 51.5239935252832,    lng:  5.137663903579778,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
    {id: '2',  lat: 51.523853342911906,  lng:  5.1377765563584035,  content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
    {id: '3',  lat: 51.5237298485607,    lng:  5.137969675407476,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
    {id: '4',  lat: 51.52355628836575,   lng:  5.138066234932012,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
    {id: '5',  lat: 51.52340275379578,   lng:  5.138211074218816,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
    {id: '6',  lat: 51.523199152806626,  lng:  5.138382735595769,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
    {id: '7',  lat: 51.5229955509073,    lng:  5.138511481628484,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
];
```

and in my html template I am writing this: `<h1 *ngFor="#location of locations">{{locations.id}}</h1>`

But it is not showing what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**//check you are creating local variable location**

```
<h1 *ngFor="#location of locations">**{{location.id}}**</h1>
```